# python not finding library under django that's found otherwise

Tags: python, django, module, geodjango, geos

I've just successfully installed GeoDjango and all the required libraries. I've set the environment variables and registry keys (yea working under Windows here) and everything works find from the command line.

```
d:\...\> python
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import *
>>> exit()
d:\...\> python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0
(...)
```

Now when the server that's being run here encounters the very same line in code it's supposed to execute, it says

```
WindowsError at /NT/BUAConvex/4DED02804:SQLEXPRESS:44_EU_2011Q2/20187417/
[Error 126] The specified module could not be found

D:\...\views.py in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.geos import * ...

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\__init__.py in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.geos.geometry import GEOSGeometry, wkt_regex, hex_regex ...

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\geometry.py in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.geos.coordseq import GEOSCoordSeq ...

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\coordseq.py in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.geos.libgeos import CS_PTR ...

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\libgeos.py in <module>
lgeos = CDLL(lib_path) ...

c:\python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__
            self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode) ...
```

Comment: This is most likely a path issue.  When you run `python.exe` it automatically adds a few directories, including the current working directory, to the path.  You can set a PYTHONPATH environment variable to specify locations where it should find included modules.

Comment: As a test, try running "python manage.py shell" and import it from there.

Comment: Where did you install the libraries to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ed. and @g.d.d.c I found the solution. Problem turned up in the Django shell as well. Turns out I had set GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = 'c:\OSGeo4W' in my Django settings where it should've been 'c:\OSGeo4W\bin'. Calling plain Python ignored those settings and instead relied on the OS-own functionality to find the .dll (which succeeds).